# How to perform motion detect using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, flash

So I want to automate youtube videos. so list of API available and also selenium have support for flash objects. My worry is that how can I check video is playing?. Like if I can perform motion detect on video I can pass or fail script accordingly. so can we achieve similar using selenium? or selenium have different approach to do this. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would check that when they click on the 'play' button it changes to the 'pause' icon; something like this:

   ```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.Iterator;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.Set;

   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
   import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;



   public class Youtube {
   public WebDriver driver;
   private String url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfhjkfocRR0";

       public Youtube() {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",     "C:\\SeleniumServer\\chromedriver.exe");
   driver = new ChromeDriver();
   //driver=new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.get(url);
   }

   public void waitFor(int wait){
        try {
       Thread.sleep(wait);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   public boolean isYoutubePlaying(){
   try {
       //wait 4 secs for Youtube video to load
       waitFor(6000);
       WebElement     playPauseButton=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.ytp-button")).get(0);
       //video is not playing here.
       if(playPauseButton.getAttribute("aria-label").equals("Play")){
           System.out.println("This Youtube video wasn't playing but we clicked on it to play the video.");
           //so we click on the play button to play the video then we return true;
           playPauseButton.click(); 
           return true;
       }else{
           //video should be playing but let's double-check
           if(playPauseButton.getAttribute("aria-label").equals("Pause")){
               System.out.println("Youtube video is already playing.");
               return true;
           }
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   //only return false if either of the 2 cases above fail.
   return false;
    }


   }//end class
   ```

And to run this code simply instantiate it like so:

```
    Youtube yt=new Youtube();
    yt.isYoutubePlaying();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply pelican. Actually this thing I already tried but this doesn't gives guarantee that video is actually started. This code will work very fine in positive scenarios but in negative scenarios it will not.

Comment: I don't think that there's any support for flash in selenium webdriver. But you can try UI automation with Sikuli. You can check for some image at the beginning of the video, in the middle and at the end of the video. Drawback's you'll have to manually save 3 images for each video. Then using Thread.sleep() to wait until video  streams to halfway, then check for the expected image with Sikuli. It's a brute force way of doing it but it'll work. If you're able to  validate that an expected image appears at start, middle and end of given youtube video, then you can conclude video loaded properly.

Comment: Ya you can correct I can use sikuli for that. But I wanted my script generic enough not dependent on resolution or size of the screen. Anyway I will up your answer because it will work but it is not the desired solution which I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks user3687223, here's a youtube video tutorial I came accross by accident and thought of your question; i'm not sure if he's serious but the guy in the video claims to be able to automate flash-based videos like youtube videos using Selenium Webdriver; here's link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z65VETxBaEM.   Here's another video by the same guy on same topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1j9GqibXeyw